# Android JNI OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface, out-of-memory

My app do the following tasks with 3321 iterations:

1. Load an image from sdcard (different image in each iteration)
2. Resize the image
3. Pass the 1-d data from native to Android
4. Pass the 1-d data from Android to native (to perform some calculation)

By the logcat, I got following messages:

```
Progress: 1 / 3321
Progress: 2 / 3321
.
.
.
Grow heap (frag case) to 5.597MB for 206132-byte allocation
.
.
.
Progress: X / 3321
Progress: X+1 / 3321
.
.
.
Grow heap (frag case) to 64.000MB for 206132-byte allocation
.
.
.
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-451 Process: com.cv.myapp, PID: 15006
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
at com.cv.myapp.SecondModule.loadImg(Native Method)
```

Task 1, 2, and 3 are done by my second module, and task 4 is done by my first module

In second module (for loading image, resizing, and pass the 1-d data):

```
/* Global variable */

Mat img;

/* JNI function */

JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL
Java_cv_myapp_SecondModule_loadImg(JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz, 
    jstring imgPath, jint height, jint width) {
    // Retrieve the string passed form JAVA
    const char* img_path = env->GetStringUTFChars(imgPath, 0);

    // Load image into OpenCV Mat object
    img = imread(img_path, IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Release the string
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(imgPath, img_path);

    // Try to resize the image if the height or width does not
    // match the given parameters
    if ( (img.rows != height) || (img.cols != width) ) 
        resize( img, img, Size(height, width) );

    // Get the float pointer that point to Mat data
    float* data = (float*) img.data;

    // Return the data from native to JAVA
    jfloatArray res = env->NewFloatArray(height * width);

    if (res == NULL)
        return NULL;

    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(res, 0, height * width, data);

    return res;
}
```

And the native function that perform task 4 in my first module:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_cv_my_app_FirstModule_processImg(JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz,
    jfloatArray img) {
    // Get the image data (float array) passed from JAVA
    jboolean is_copied;
    jint img_size = env->GetArrayLength(img);
    jfloat* img_data = env->GetFloatArrayElements(img, &is_copied);

    // Do some calculation on variable img_data, 
    // and storing the result to the global variable.

    // Release the image data
    if (is_copied == JNI_TRUE)
        env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(img, img_data, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

In Android:

```
FirstModule first_module = new FirstModule();
SecondModule second_module = new SecondModule();

// Load image paths into variable imgSet
// Each image path can be retrieved by imgSet[i]

// 3321 iterations
for (int i=0 ; i<3321 ; ++i) {
    first_module.processImg(    
        second_module.loadImg( imgSet[i] )
    );
}
```

I guess the `OutOfMemoryError` may be due to transfer the data between native and JAVA, but I'm not sure (the error may be due to other reasons).
What's wrong with my code?
Many thanks!

Edit:

I replaced

```
if (is_copied == JNI_TRUE)
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(img, img_data, JNI_ABORT);
```

with

```
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(img, img_data, JNI_ABORT);
```

, and the following log is printed. It seems that garbage collection occurred.

```
Progress: 301 / 3321

Clamp target GC heap from 65.488MB to 64.000MB
Grow heap (frag case) to 64.000MB for 206132-byte allocation

Progress: 302 / 3321
Progress: 303 / 3321

Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 206132-byte allocation
GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 61959K, 96% free 3192K/65408K, paused 21ms, total 24ms

Progress: 304 / 3321
Progress: 305 / 3321

Grow heap (frag case) to 4.272MB for 206132-byte allocation

Progress: 306 / 3321
.
.
.
```

Garbage collection also occurred after 603 iteration.

```
Progress: 603 / 3321

Clamp target GC heap from 64.563MB to 64.000MB
Grow heap (frag case) to 64.000MB for 206132-byte allocation

Progress: 604 / 3321
Progress: 605 / 3321
Progress: 606 / 3321

Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 206132-byte allocation
GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 61219K, 87% free 3185K/24008K, paused 34ms, total 38ms
Progress: 607 / 3321
.
.
.
```

But the app crashed after the following log printed

```
Progress: 642 / 3321
Grow heap (frag case) to 12.474MB for 206132-byte allocation
Progress: 643 / 3321
```

And there is no other log follows log "Progress: 643 / 3321"

Edit2:

I added

```
LOGI("Release Mat.");
img.release();
LOGI("Release Mat ... ok");
```

before

```
return res;
```

in second module.

And the log shows

```
I/SecondModuleJNI: Release Mat.
I/SecondModuleJNI: Release Mat ... ok
I/FirstModuleJNI: Progress: 1 / 3321
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.816MB for 206132-byte allocation
```

before the app crashed.

Comment: `Mat img` is not released in your second module.

Comment: @DavidMiguel But as long as it's one single copy of reused object it should be fine.

Comment: How about setting android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_copied == JNI_TRUE)
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(img, img_data, JNI_ABORT);
```

`ReleaseFloatArrayElements()` should always be called no matter it's copied or not. Otherwise the reference count to the array may not be decreased and cannot be garbage collected.